# Не могу получить файл с сервера NGINX

Tags: php

Добрый день, не могу скачать файл с сервера. Скрипт таки возвращает файл, но размер его 0 байт.

```
$file = 'http://2ch.hk/newtest/resources/images/dvlogo.png';

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
exit(0);
```

Comment: 1 - что вы пытаетесь сделать этим заголовком: `header('http://video.aniland.org/32728122.mp4');`? 2 - вы понимаете, что сам файл вы ***не*** отдаете?

Comment: Забыл удалить, осталось от многочисленных тестов. Что-то по существу будет?

Comment: будет. Только опишите, какое поведение вы ожидаете - скачивание файла с локального для скрипта хоста, или все-таки с удаленного?

Comment: "с локального для скрипта хоста, или все-таки с удаленного?" Не совсем понял. Но этот скрипт у меня на платном хостинге. Так что, наверное, первый  вариант.

Comment: С локального...

Comment: боюсь, полноценно раньше завтра не отвечу

Comment: Ничего, подожду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в вопросе описаны только *заголовки* ответа, в то время как никаких данных сервер не отдает - потому и скачивается документ в ноль байт. В случае, если у вас есть ссылка на конкретный документ, то проще всего отдать ее пользователю с 301/302 редиректом:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Temporarily Moved');
header('Location: ' . $url);
```

В случае, если документ валяется на диске исполняющей код машины, его надо *прочитать* и *вывести* в теле ответа. Проще всего использовать функцию `readfile()`:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $filename);
readfile($file);
```

Comment: Уже  разобрался, использовал **readfile($file);**. Спасибо за ответ.